# Div container overflowing a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

After setting all parents to height of 100% and adding a new div container above my map, I get this overflow of the map container within the row. The new div above the map is this and is the `locationQuickSearch` id :

[image]

[image]

Where does this come from?

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-container container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mapContainer">
                <!-- Quicksearch -->
                <div id="LocationQuickSearch">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Addresse</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="searchAddress" v-model="searchAddress" placeholder="Bitte geben Sie eine Suchaddresse ein." v-on:focus='clearFormFields'>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!-- GIS MAP -->
                <div id="GISMap" v-el:map></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Form -->
            <div class="col-md-7 incidentContainer">
                <div class="incidentForm"> (...)

#LocationQuickSearch {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

// --Page Content
#page-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.row, .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.row .mapContainer {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.row .incidentContainer {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.incidentForm {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: You want the map to be displayed under the div with the grey background, is that correct?

Comment: Actually it should be within the gray background. The gray background represents the `row`

Comment: Do I need to use another div to wrap both (quicksearch and map)?

Comment: And I would also like to understand, why this overflow is happening. I am really new to layouting with CSS/Bootstrap and it would be great to learn more

Comment: Can you please post a jsfiddle or similar with the complete code, including the map script?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53ffb6bz/

Comment: Hm... well.. I don't see why

Comment: could it be that this is caused due to a collapsed height due to floating child elements within the parent div?

Comment: anyone having an idea?